# Why duplicated iptables rule is matched more times than it's first occurence?

Tags: iptables, docker

I am observing weird behavior on iptables with docker swarm.
Maybe somebody could explain what's happening there.
First zeroing counters on FORWARD chain with `iptables -Z FORWARD`, then after a minute `iptables -L FORWARD -n -v --line-numbers`:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     115K   62M DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    57041   57M DOCKER-INGRESS  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3    1299K 1009M DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4    1299K 1009M DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
5        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
6        0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
7        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
8        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
9     154K  159M ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker_gwbridge  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
10    5420  299K DOCKER     all  --  *      docker_gwbridge  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
11   1140K  850M ACCEPT     all  --  docker_gwbridge !docker_gwbridge  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
12       0     0 DROP       all  --  docker_gwbridge docker_gwbridge  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

To make sure that rule number 1 and 3 are the same I ran `iptables -S FORWARD`:

```
-P FORWARD DROP
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-INGRESS
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker_gwbridge -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker_gwbridge -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker_gwbridge ! -o docker_gwbridge -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker_gwbridge -o docker_gwbridge -j DROP
```

I know that duplicated rules sometimes happen, but why second occurence of rule has more packets counted (1299K) than the first one (115K)?